# caml query pass username dynamically in sharepoint hosted app

Tags: list, list-view, caml-query, sharepoint-hosted-app, schema

In my hosted app I have one text field which contains username. I have write following query in lists schema.xml

```
<View>
    <Query>
        <Where>
            <Contains>
                <FieldRef Name='Title'/>
                <Value Type='Text'>uname</Value>
            </Contains>
        </Where>
    </Query>
</View>
```

I want  to replace the ***uname*** by current user login name.I dont know this will work or not . Please suggest some help for this situation

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
<View>
        <Query>
            <Where>
                <Contains>
                    <FieldRef Name='Title'/>
                    <Value Type='Text'><UserID/></Value>
                </Contains>
            </Where>
        </Query> 
   </View>
```

Comment: This would not work if the text column contains the user name only, as described in the question?